# getting double quote when reading from a csv file

Tags: python, string, csv

when i read data from a csv, its supposed to end as string, but when im printing it it contains double quote, is there any efficient way to avoid this different than replace?

my case is this:

```
def map_line(line):
    line = line.split(",")
    date = line[1]
    print(date)

lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file_name.csv")
lines_result = lines.map(map_line)
```

but when printing date, i get:

```
"[16/Nov/2017:16:17:31"
```

how can i remove then?

Comment: Whoever wrote the data messed up in the writing stage because your data actually contains a list that you read as part of the string. The [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) was specifically designed for reading and writing CSVs. You cannot reliably split a file on any delimiter and get the correct format back out; it's perfectly valid for "Hello, Jefer" to be a single entry, for example

Comment: Why do it in traditional way when there are modules like `panda` and `csv` which can read csv files easily?